# error: request for member (maybe you meant to use '->' ?) while using '->' already

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, compiler-errors, dynamic-allocation

Is there an easy explanation for what this error means?

> error: request for member 'Attributes' in '* printerInfo', which is of
>   pointer type 'PPRINTER_INFO_2 {aka _PRINTER_INFO_2A*}' (maybe you
>   meant to use '->' ?)

```
PPRINTER_INFO_2* printerInfo = NULL;

    void ChangedPrinter()
    {
       ...
       DWORD attributesPrinterInfo;

       printerInfo = (PPRINTER_INFO_2*) malloc(bufferSize);

       attributesPrinterInfo = printerInfo->Attributes; // error

       free(printerInfo);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Of which type are `AttributesPrinterInfo` and `printerInfo->Atteibutes`? It seems to me that the one is a pointer, the other one is a struct.

Comment: The two are of the same type DWORD.
attributesPrinterInfo is not a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PRINTER_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162845(v=vs.85).aspx) structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct _PRINTER_INFO_2 {
  // ...
} PRINTER_INFO_2, *PPRINTER_INFO_2;
```

so `PPRINTER_INFO_2` is pointer to `PRINTER_INFO_2`. When you do

```
printerInfo = (PPRINTER_INFO_2*) malloc(bufferSize);
```

`printerInfo` actually becomes a pointer to pointer to `PRINTER_INFO_2`. I'm not sure whether this was an intention or just a mistake, but if it's intended to be `PPRINTER_INFO_2*` then proper usage is:

```
(*printerInfo)->Attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

for Cpp,
See this https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91138

Suggesting -> isn't helpful when it already uses it. The right fix-it is to suggest (*pp)->member